# Resize header image only for phones?

Tags: css, resize, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a Wordpress site where I have a background image that serves as my logo and my actual header image is transparent. Due to the way the header image resizes on mobile, there is a big empty space between my logo (the background image) and everything below it when viewed on a phone. It looks great on desktop & a tablet.

Is there a way that I can resize the height of that transparent header image only on a phone, without messing up the size of it on desktop or tablet?

You can [view my site here](http://www.gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/), if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier to show in actual code but you can adjust the sizes and only make it impact the sizes you define with media queries - [read more about here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

If you look at the screenshot, you can see that the `a` tag had a height of 150px. If you regulate it a bit, the space between logo and menu won't be as far.

Here is an example that will make the new change of `height` on the `.header-image .site-title a` only on sizes less that `450px`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .header-image .site-title a {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

`max-width` means when ever the screen is under 450px, `min-width` would be over.
This was just an example, you can change it to whatever you prefer and you can of course add multiple media queries.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much! I used that code but changed it to 60px and that is exactly what I was wanting. I really appreciate your help! I'm new to this so I appreciate you explaining what everything does. It's been fun to learn about :)